# LINQ results when there are no matches?

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause

What exactly does a LINQ function return when there are no matches? Take the Where method, for example:

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);
var results = numbers.Where(n => n == 50);
```

What would be in results at this point?

Comment: What would be in "results" is *an object which represents the query*. Remember: the query object is NOT the results of the query. The query object is something you can *iterate to obtain the results of the query*, it is not itself the results.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`results` itself is just a query. Until you start to iterate through it (either explicitly or via a call like `Count()`), nothing has checked whether there are any results or not. It's only when you enumerate it that anything will happen.

So you could do:

```
foreach (int x in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This won't happen");
}
```

Or:

```
Console.WriteLine(results.Any()); // Will print false
Console.WriteLine(results.Count()); // Will print 0
```

Any of these will cause the predicate to be evaluated against each item in the range... but before then, it won't be called at all.

This is an important thing to understand, because it means that `results` *couldn't* be `null` while retaining the feature of lazy evaluation - until you tried to *use* `results`, it wouldn't have worked out whether it should be `null` or not!

Comment: I forgot all about lazy evaluation. *smacks self*

Comment: Note that the "query" you're speaking of really is an IEnumerable of some sort which hasn't actually populated it's data...

Answer (score 4):

In this case it returns an `IEnumerable<Int32>` with a count of 0 items.

Comment: That makes it sound like it "knows" there's a count of 0 - which it doesn't. The returned value is an `IEnumerable<Int32>` which, when iterated over, will yield 0 items. It doesn't know that beforehand though - it has to try the predicate against each value to find out, and it doesn't do that until you ask it to.

Comment: @Jon: definitely, thanks for clarifying. As you mentioned in your post, it has to be used to determine the result.

Answer (score 3):

A reference to an empty `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Excellent! That's what I was looking for. I wanted to be sure that I didn't have to check for null.

Comment: Nitpick: A reference to an empty IEnumerable<T> - not a collection

Comment: @Mark Yes I though about clarifying.