# LINQ IQueryable Check if Empty without Enumerating

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lazy-evaluation

This might sound like a ridiculous question, but I couldn't find a straight answer anywhere.

I have a function that returns an `IQueryable<MyObject>` object from a LINQ-to-SQL query.  I know that IQueryable objects utilize lazy evaluation, so I don't want to enumerate it by using `.Count` prior to returning the object.  However, I would like to check that it is not "null" or empty prior to passing it back to the caller.  The reasoning is that if the query returns no results it means the caller passed an invalid parameter, therefore I would like to throw an exception.

This question: [LINQ results when there are no matches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533155/linq-results-when-there-are-no-matches) didn't seem to provide a straight answer for my version of this question.

My question is:  Is there a way to check if an IQueryable object is empty without enumerating it?  Would checking against `default(IQueryable<T>)` do the trick?

Comment: I would rather not evaluate the query prior to passing it back to the caller.  Any will evaluate the query.

Comment: @JNYRanger, how does your question make any logical sense?  How can you know if the query will return results without executing it!?

Comment: No, there's no way to see if an arbitrary query returns any results without running the query. Now, you don't have to go to the trouble of enumerating the whole query, or selecting more than one value, but `Any()` will do this intelligently.

Comment: @TimS. Of course, the time spent iterating the rest of an in memory collection generally pales in comparison to the time spent communicating with a DB over the network, unless your query has a very large result set.  Not that it's a bad idea though if you really do just need to know if there are any items.  Also note that the use of `Any` on an `IQueryable` will alter the query to only return one item, making the DB execution and network load faster/lighter.

Comment: @KirkWoll Essentially, I was trying to figure out if there was a faster way to handle this rather than evaluating an `IQueryable` object, then passing it back to the caller and letting them use it (again).  Based on Servy & TimS's comments I will evaluate the query within the function and then pass an `IEnumerable` instead to the caller.  Thanks for the info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to check if an IQueryable object is empty without enumerating it?

No, that's impossible.

The only way to determine if the query has at least one result is to actually execute the query.  You don't need to iterate the entire result set, but you need to try to fetch the first item, which means sending the query to the database, having it execute it, and send the response.

If it's really essential that you do this you're probably best off just pulling the entire result set into memory, into say a list, doing your check, and then returning an `IEnumerable` rather than an `IQueryable`.

That, or just don't do the check.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for, a simple no =)  I guess I'll leave it up to the caller.

Comment: Why not `AsEnumerable`!That would execute query locally!

Comment: @Anirudh How would that possibly help?  You still need to go to the db and execute the query.  What does the use of `AsEnumerable` give you?

Comment: @Anirudh Please re-read my question that is not what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a `.Any()` in your LINQ statement prior to returning it. That way you will get a null value if your statement doesn't return anything.

Comment: That is executing the query.  Also, if there are no items it results in an empty sequence, not `null`, and `Any` then returns `false`, again, not `null`.

Comment: The catch is that I don't want to evaluate the query prior to returning it.

Comment: @JNYRanger, how can you *conceivably* get the results of a query wihtout executing it?  I am confused how you are asking for anything short of magic.

Comment: @JNYRanger think in the case of `SQL query` first, how could you achieve what you want with `SQL query`? As for the translation, the problem can be re-stated like this `How could I know if there is any data without having to execute the SQL query?`

Comment: @Servy you misunderstood me, please read it again, **I also mean he can't**

Comment: @KirkWoll Magic would be nice for this.  To be honest I just wanted to make sure I understood how the IQueryable object worked.  Servy provided the answer i was looking for above.

Comment: @KingKing Thanks for the explanation, that makes complete sense.